# Can't use Multi-line editing but multi-cursor works in Visual Studio Code

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

There's a nice feature when editing in multiple locations at once called [multi-line editing](https://kencenerelli.wordpress.com/2018/03/25/visual-studio-code-multi-line-and-multi-cursor-editing/).

I can confirm that I can activate editing in multiple location at once if I click there while holding Alt key. However, it doesn't seem to activate when I go to the next line with an arrow key while holding Alt key down.

I've tried that both with and without Shift key pressed. I removed the other actions connected to those key combinations. I've checked the settings and keybinding for anything line multi-whatever. Googling the issue leads only to blogs discussing that great feature.

How can I troubleshoot it further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>up/downArrow</kbd>

Search for "cursor" in the Keyboard Shortcuts:

`editor.action.insertCursorAbove` **Add Cursor Above**` for example

so multi-line search doesn't really help, "cursor" does because vscode refers to it as `multi-cursor` editing, not `multi-line`.

Comment: Somehow, the default binding got disconnected, so the default combo didn't work (I'm referring to your comment). However, the **name** of the command did the trick. I was looking for it using wrong terms, missed the *cursor* being main component.